Trying to construct Response surface involving unequal variance for the data mentioned using Minitab
I'm new to Minitab and I never learned statistics as a proper subject.
I need to get a response surface and CI for a factorial experiment for my thesis. I'm faced with what looks like unequal and bimodal variance (see figures). I can't use Box-Cox because of negative response. What should I do to get a regression that properly describe my data? I'm in a big hurry, so a step-by-step guide (with equations if I'm to calculate something) to avoid possible back-and-forths due to things being unclear would be much appreciated. And if I'm worrying for nothing and the data is distributed reasonably normally, how do I defend that?





It looks to me like you (grossly) overinterpret these plots.  After all, they reflect only 18 observations.  The interesting part of your question concerns how to back up this opinion.  One excellent approach is called the "statistical lineup" by Cook et al..  Here is a paper on applying it to regression diagnostics: https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.05964 .
